# cannot set innerHTML of null and nothing i tried has worked

Tags: javascript, html, dom

i am programing a clicking game and using javascript and im trying to use .innerHTML but it creates an error called cannot set innerHTML of null, I have serched on this website for a while and have found solutions like putting the html stuff before the js, but nothing is working

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Prison Clicker</title>
    <style>

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Aquire</h1>
    <p id="cigarets_show">0</p>
    <button onClick="clicking()">CLICK</button>
    <script>
      var cigaretts = 0;
      var cigarettsPC = 0;
       function clicking(){
         cigaretts += cigarettsPC;
       }
       setInterval(
         function showvariables(){
           var cigaretts_show = document.getElementById("cigaretts_show")
           cigaretts_show.innerHTML = cigaretts;
         }
       )
    </script>

  </body>
```

Comment: well then, `cigaretts_show` must be null. is that so complicated?

Comment: how do i change this

Comment: Always check your spelling. A quick proofread identifies the source of the problem.

Comment: @SumanLama that's not the problem. The script is being executed, but `innerHTML` of a null reference is being accessed due to a probable typo. This causes an error.

Answer (score 1):

You have spelling mistakes. Also you have setInterval with no time.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Prison Clicker</title>
    <style>

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Aquire</h1>
    <p id="cigarets_show">0</p>
    <button onClick="clicking()">CLICK</button>
    <script>
      var cigaretts = 0;
      var cigarettsPC = 1;
       function clicking(){
         cigaretts += cigarettsPC;
       }
       setInterval(
         function showvariables(){
           var cigaretts_show = document.getElementById("cigarets_show")
           cigaretts_show.innerHTML = cigaretts;
         } , 1000
       )
    </script>

  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using incorrect id.. So it is showing error

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Prison Clicker</title>
    <style>

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Aquire</h1>
    <p id="cigarets_show">0</p>
    <button onClick="clicking()">CLICK</button>
    <script>
      var cigaretts = 0;
      var cigarettsPC = 0;
       function clicking(){
         cigaretts += cigarettsPC;
       }
       setInterval(
         function showvariables(){
           var cigaretts_show = document.getElementById("cigarets_show")
           cigaretts_show.innerHTML = cigaretts;
         }
       )
    </script>

  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify your code as follows:

```js
var element = document.getElementById("count");
var count = 0;

function increment(){
  count++;
  element.innerText = count;
}
```

```html
<h1>Aquire</h1>
<p id="count">0</p>
<button onClick="increment()">CLICK</button>
```